# Pyspark make non-streaming copy of dataframe

Tags: pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a dataframe that reads from a delta table:

```py
stream = spark.readStream.table("my_table")
```

Before writing I want to do transformations on the stream content. I need to perform certain things in batches and with external executables. What I really need is a copy of stream that is not "streaming". Ideally:

```py
my_copy = stream.alias("my_copy")
print(my_copy.isStreaming)  # I need this False

# Do inexplicable things to my_copy ;)

new_df = stream.alias("a").join(my_copy.alias("b"), "a.x" == "b.y")
print(new_df.isStreaming)  # Please be True

new_df.writeStream.toTable("somewhere")
```

The problem is that with my_copy at some point I need to do .groupBy().count().collect() and then I get a message about

`Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()`